# Error starting Hive: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hive/conf/HiveConf

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hive

I have downloaded latest stable release of Hive, when I start /usr/local/hive/bin/hive it gives me this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hive/conf/HiveConf
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:149)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
... 3 more
```

Hadoop DFS is started and working, and I have changed /usr/local/hive/conf/hive-env.sh to export HADOOP_HOME.

Does anyone know what else can I do?
Thanks.

Comment: This is because your classpath is not properly set. Could you please describe how you installed Hive?

Comment: I downloaded Hive from http://apache.rediris.es/hive/stable/hive-0.8.1.tar.gz
Then moved to /usr/local and gave it 777 permissions.

If I type "echo $CLASSPATH" in console, I get: /usr/local/hive/bin/:/usr/local/hive/lib/:/usr/local/hadoop/bin/ among other directories.

Which variable or path is Hive expecting to find?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from editing hive-env.sh, you also need to edit your bash_profile.

```
vim ~/.bash_profile
```

Add the following lines to your bash_profile

```
export HIVE_HOME=/usr/local/hive
export PATH=$PATH:$HIVE_HOME/bin
```

Save this file and then

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

If this still doesnt work, please include your hive-env.sh file and hive-site.xml file. Also please tell me if you are using derby or mysql as metastore.

Comment: Made those changes to ~./bashrc but still doesn't work.

hive-env.sh
    export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop

hive-site.xml: doesn't exist in conf directory.

Also I don't have any metastore installed, it doesn't say anything about it there: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/GettingStarted#GettingStarted-InstallingHivefromaStableRelease

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I do have metastore, created it as it says on getting started:

$ $HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop fs -mkdir       /tmp
  $ $HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop fs -mkdir       /user/hive/warehouse
  $ $HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop fs -chmod g+w   /tmp
  $ $HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop fs -chmod g+w   /user/hive/warehouse

Comment: Can you please echo out HADOOP_HOME and HIVE_HOME. Since you have not specifically configured for mysql metastore, this means you are using derby (else the problem might be something related to mysql connector which we can avoid for now). Can you please once add this to bash_profile as well and tell me what happens?

Comment: HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop HIVE_HOME=/usr/local/hive. Those variables are exported in ~/.bashrc but still getting the same error.

Comment: Also I have in hadoop-env.sh: export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=/usr/local/hbase/hbase-0.94.1.jar:/usr/local/hbase/hbase-0.94.1-test.jar:/usr/local/hbase/conf:/usr/local/hbase/lib/zookeeper-3.4.3.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/*.jar

Comment: Ok, I am assuming you have installed hbase as well. If so please do chang HADOOP_CLASSPATH as follows

export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_CLASSPATH:/usr/hbase/lib and please do erase what you have already written. Zookeeper and hive libs need not be in the classpath.  If this still fails then try copying hive-commons.jar present in /usr/local/hive/lib to /usr/local/hadoop/lib (This is not the right way but works for some people)

Answer (score 0):

Solved moving:

```
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=/usr/local/hbase/hbase-0.94.1.jar:/usr/local/hbase/hbase-0.94.1-test.jar:/usr/local/hbase/conf:/usr/local/hbase/lib/zookeeper-3.4.3.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/*.jar:/usr/local/hbase
```

From **/usr/local/hadoop/conf/hadoop-env.sh** to **~/.bashrc**

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

if you are facing this issue in sqoop while hive-imports
then you need to copy hive-common-3.1.2.jar (or whichever version of hive-common-x.x.x.jar) from the $HIVE_HOME/lib folder and paste it into the $SQOOP_HOME/lib folder and the error will be gone